# How to change name tag on old Kompakt intercom

Tags: building

I have bought apartment in old building and want to change name tag on Kompakt intercom.
Plastic in front of name tag can't be move without breaking.

[image]

Comment: That appears to be a low-resolution stock picture. A high resolution picture (preferably of the real thing) would be more helpful, but it suggests unscrewing the faceplate as a first approach, since there appears to be a screw in the lower center. Or, given the name, just have the local KGB agent take are of it!

Comment: Funny, @Ecnerwal, but probably not really all that appropriate.

Comment: I have called my KGB agent,... I mean tenant representative. He unscrewed cover and replaced name tag.

Comment: Got to admit - I thought MTA's answer would have been the correct one - I up voted it. Though I can see where that simple solution wouldn't be appropriate in a secured building, since people could change the names at random to mess with others... Thanks for coming back to wrap this one up.

Comment: Two screws are here [link](https://imgur.com/a/7AeoNeW) under plastic. So first you have to push to open then unscrew, take whole cover to replace name tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If there's some sort of centralized maintenance person/company responsible for taking care of common areas, I'd suggest contacting them as they probably know how, and may (eventually?) get around to doing it without you even having to ask.

If there isn't a maintenance person (or they're taking too long for your tastes), look for the next newest looking name tag in the intercom. Press the button next to it, introduce yourself as the new neighbor and ask the person how (s)he replaced the name tag.

Answer (score 2):

I had a device like that many years ago.

Look for a small hole in the location marked with the red dot below. Use the end of a paper clip in the hole to pry the plastic cover toward the right, and it will pop out. After you replace the name tag, insert the plastic cover into the right side, then bend it slightly until it pops into the left side.

Repeat for each name that needs to be replaced.
[image]

Comment: Honestly, this has 99.99% chance of being right. If not, my answer is a good fall back.